# Passar informações de um item selecionado na lista para os EditText

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

Olá, estou com problemas quado seleciono um cliente em uma *ListView*, eu tenho que passar o nome dele para um *EditText* da outra Activity e passar o endereço também.

Só que quando seleciono o Cliente ele esta agrupando o Nome com o Endereço na mesma linha.
E tenho outro problema em relação ao toString, em como passar todos os dados da tabela sem que me de *NullPointer* ou apareça valores `NULL`.

**Segue códigos:**

```
{       

    /**
     * Método de listagem dos clientes
     */
    public List<Cliente> listarClientes() {

        // List que recebe os dados que são percorridos no while
        List<Cliente> listaClientes = new ArrayList<Cliente>();
        // Variável para utilizar a query no Cursor
        String sql = "select * from dj_tb_cli";
        // Objeto que recebe os registros do Banco de Dados
        Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(sql, null);

        try {
            // Percorre todos os registros do cursor
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
                // Carrega os atributos do Banco de Dados
                cliente.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
                cliente.setNomeCliente(cursor.getString(1));
                cliente.setEnderecoCliente(cursor.getString(6));

                listaClientes.add(cliente);

                Log.i(TAG, "Listando Clientes");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(TAG, e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            // Garante o fechamento do Banco de Dados
            cursor.close();
        }
        return listaClientes;
    }
}
```

**Minha ListView.**

```
public class ListaClientesBD extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener {

    private String clienteSel;
    private String endSel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        DatabasesDAO db = new DatabasesDAO(this);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Cliente>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, db.listarClientes()));
        ListView listView = getListView();
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    // private List<String> listarClientes() {
    // return Arrays.asList("Cliente 1", "Cliente 2", "Cliente 3");
    // }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {

        TextView textView = (TextView) view;

        String mensagem = "Cliente Selecionado: " + textView.getText();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mensagem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        // startActivity(new Intent(this, NovoPedidoActivity.class));

        Intent intent = new Intent(ListaClientesBD.this,
                TelaNovoPedidoActivity.class);

        clienteSel = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra("cliente", clienteSel.toString());

        endSel = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra("endCliente", endSel.toString());

        startActivity(intent);
}
```

**Esse trecho esta na minha Activity. Ele recebe os valores pela chave do item selecionado na lista.**

```
    nomeCliente = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nmClienteBD);
    String parametroCli = getIntent().getStringExtra("cliente");
    nomeCliente.setText(parametroCli);

    enderecoCliente = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.endClienteBD);
    String parametroEndCli = getIntent().getStringExtra("endCliente");
    enderecoCliente.setText(parametroEndCli);

    EditText nomeProduto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.produtoBD);
    String parametroProd = getIntent().getStringExtra("nmProd");
    nomeProduto.setText(parametroProd);
```

Answer (score 2):

Rapaz, não é aconselhado trabalhar com ArrayList de Objetos para montar listViews em android. 
Para rodar liso e mais estável, o mais indicado é usar HashMaps de Strings com chave valor.

Quanto ao seu projeto, especificamente, vc tá usando o *android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1* para montar seu listview, um layout que possui apenas 1 textview, e depois você utiliza este mesmo textview para setar o contato e o endereço, por isso que tá vindo tudo junto, entende?

Eu te indicaria fazer o seguinte... Montar teu HashMap, a partir do teu cursor, e criar seu próprio adapter para montar a lista.

**ArrayList de HashMap, populado pelo cursor**

```
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    map.put("chaveNome",cursor.getString(1));
    map.put("chaveEndereco", cursor.getString(6));

    fillMaps.add(map);

    ExemploAdapter adapter = new ExemploAdapter(this, fillMaps);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Layout pro item da sua lista - *R.layout.list_item***

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            style="@style/TextViewSize"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            style="@style/TextViewMinimumSize"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

**Estrutura do seu Adapter**

```
public class ExemploAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

public ExemploAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.data = data;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    //retorna seu objeto    
    return data.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //monta o layout de cada item da sua lista
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

    TextView nome = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView endereco = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    HashMap<String, String> list = new HashMap<String, String>();
    list = data.get(position);

    nome.setText(list.get("chaveNome"));
    endereco.setText(list.get("chaveEndereco"));

    return vi;
}

}
```

**E no clique é só correr pro abraço ;)**

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,final long id) {
            Object obj = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
        }
    });
```

Acho que deu pra entender :)
Boa sorte!

Comment: Fiquei um tempo fora, vou dar uma olhada e te falo se funcionou.. Cheguei em alguns problemas aqui no desenvolvimento que fiquei travado..

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia,

Bom vamos ver se entendi você está querendo pegar o valor de um EditText dentro de um determinado item de uma `ListView` certo?

Bom se for isso está bem equivocado, o ideal seria trabalhar com o array de objetos que está no seu adapter que seria uma List, nele você iria extrair o item que você deseja e prosseguir daí, enfim você deve fazer algo asism:

No método  `public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)`, use o parâmetro position com o método `getItem(int arg0)`, ele retorna o Cliente e com ele você pode pegar o cliente desejado e buscar as informações.

Não consigo testar de onde estou, mas é algo assim:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {

    Cliente cliente =  (Cliente) getListAdapter().getItem(position);

    //Continue daqui
}
```

Comment: No meu código passo o parametro do cliente para ser presentado no EditText. Quando ele aparece ele esta agrupando o Cliente com Endereço. E no meu toString quando eu dou append com outras informações ai que mistura tudo.
Você teria algo para exemplificar em código?
Tenho pouco tempo em desenvolvimento Android.

Comment: @user2362558, adicionei a minha resposta, veja se te atende.

Comment: Eu entendi o que você quis dizer.. Mas mesmo assim, estou com dificuldades aqui. Tem muitas coisas que são novas ainda pra mim.
Por exemplo pra eu fazer o get do nome e do endereço, como passo a posição?

esse feriado promete ser longo pra estudar todas essas coias.rs

Comment: @user2362558, você precisa implementar o método onItemClick, nele um dos parametros é o "position" você o usa para pegar a posição e chegar ao valor desejado no Array que está no adapter. Fique a vontade para perguntar o que quiser, mas sugiro reformular sua pergunta e adicionar tudo que tenha dúvida, assim responderei melhor

Comment: Ok, eu vou elaborar aqui um descritivo das minhas dúvidas em relação a isso para te passar.